# Is this a misuse of asynchronous methods?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcpclient

I'm facing asynchronous methods for the first time and I cannot understand the advantages of the following code on a synchronous version:

```
    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);

        // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
        SendCompleted.Set();
    }

    private AutoResetEvent SendCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public bool Send(byte[] byteData)
    {
        try
        {
            RfTcpClient.Client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                   new AsyncCallback(this.SendCallback), RfTcpClient.Client);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return SendCompleted.WaitOne(1000, true);
    }
```

I simplified it a bit so don't care about trivial error !

The **Send** method starts sending the message and then waits till the operation is completed without wasting cpu time. A new thread executes **SendCallback** which writes on the communication channel and it **actively** wait for the operation to complete, then signal the thread of the **Send** method.

I cannot see any advantages on synchronous method.
My assumption is that **client.EndSend** costs cpu time till it is completed, so the synchronous method is only moved to another thread. Am I missing something ?

Comment: What's the point in using async methods if you are blocking manually? Why don't you just use `Send` then?

Comment: You can just use regular `Send` and configure appropriate `SendTimeout` to achieve the same result.

Comment: That code comes form a library I have to use and I cannot understand if it is smart and I'm not or it is the contrary. From your comments it seems you agree it is over complicated without any real advantage.